# RulesAction to send notification for specific users after node has been created

Tags: 8, users, rules

### The Background

I'm using the module 'Permissions by Term' (https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term) to make some nodes only visible to users which are allowed to see the assigned term. This works pretty well for me. However, I also need to notify those users that a new node has been created, which seems to be a lot more challenging.

### The Challenge

Whenever a node with Permissions by Term is published, notify all users which are allowed to see this node, that it has been created.

### The Solution

I created a Rule, which is triggered whenever new content is created. I also created a custom RulesAction to send the notifications. The parameter submitted to the RulesAction is the newly created node.

### The Problem

It looks like `$node->access('view', $user) === TRUE` is always TRUE for newly created nodes.

```
protected function doExecute($node) {

    $users = user_load_multiple();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($node->access('view', $user) === TRUE) {
            // SEND NOTIFICATION HERE
        }
    }
}
```

This always sends notification to all users.

I also thought about rebuilding the node access table before checking for access like this:

```
protected function doExecute($node) {

    $nid = $node->id();

    $node->save();

    // rebuild the node_access table
    node_access_rebuild();

    // reload the node - maybe unnecessary?
    $node = node_load($nid);

    $users = user_load_multiple();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($node->access('view', $user) === TRUE) {
            // SEND NOTIFICATION HERE
        }
    }
}
```

But no success.

### The Question

Doesn't Permission by Term affect the $node->access at all? If so, what other query can I use to check if a certain user is allowed to view the newly created node?

Thank you very much!

Comment: node_load will bypass the database by default. Try node_load ($nid, TRUE);

Comment: Also, node_access_rebuild() is potentially an expensive operation which might time out, so you might want to see if it works without it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I've had a look into the code of the module and it seems like the hook_node_access method which is part of the module completely ignores the User parameter of the node_access method. Instead it always uses the currentUser which of course is the admin user in my case. So it will always return TRUE when checking for access. I'll contact the developers of the module and try to contribute :)